# Combining two sequential backend responses to construct the frontend response

Tags: netty

Netty 4.0 server that makes two outbound requests for every incoming request, and uses the responses of the outbound requests to form the response to the original inbound request.  Outbound 1 response is used to build Outbound 2 request if successful.

See diagram here: https://twitter.com/puffybsd/status/437652876928626688/photo/1

Here's what I'm doing now (just a test with 1 remote host):

1. Create a standard ServerBootstrap with a pipeline that contains a `SimpleInboundChannelHandler<FullHttpRequest>` call it `HandlerA`.
2. When `HandlerA` receives a `channelActive` event, create a new Bootstrap, register a new Handler, `HandlerB`, open the connection to the 1st remote host and store the channel `ChannelB` in a variable of `HandlerA`.
3. When `HandlerA` receives a `read0` event, extract parameters from the `FullHttpRequest` object, build a `FullHttpResponse` object and store it in an attribute of the `ChannelB` variable along with the current context.
4. Send a request to the first remote host.
5. When `HandlerB` receives a `FullHttpResponse` from remote host 1, extract the original context and `FullHttpResponse` object from the `ChannelB` attribute set.
6. Update the `FullHttpResponse` and write it to the original context's channel.

This appears to work.  Haven't added the 2nd remote host call yet.  The two backend remote hosts do not change - they're always the same addresses.  What it appears to be doing is opening a socket to the backend when there's a new client request, sending a request to the backend, then sending a response to the client when a response from the backend is received.

Here's some code:

```
public class MainIncomingRequestHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {
   private Channel outboundChannel;

   @Override
   public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

         Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
         bootstrap.group(ctx.channel().eventLoop());
         bootstrap.channel(ctx.channel().getClass());
         bootstrap.handler(new IncomingResponseHandler());

         outboundChannel = channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(host, port).channel();
    }  

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg)
        throws Exception {
        //create a response object.

        //save the response to the outboundChannel's attribute map.
        outboundChannel.attr(CONTEXT_KEY).set(ctx);
        outboundChannel.attr(RESPONSE_KEY).set(response);

        //create a request and write it to the outboundChannel.
        outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(req);
    }
}

public class IncomingResponseHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpResponse> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpResponse inboundResponse)
        throws Exception {

        //extract data from the remote response.  
        //...      

       //fetch the original context and response from the channel attributes.
       ChannelHandlerContext ctx = ctx.channel().attr(CONTEXT_KEY).get();
       FullHttpResponse response = ctx.channel().attr(OUTBOUND_RESPONSE_KEY).get();

       //update the outbound response with results from the inbound response.
       //...

       //send the response to the original inbound request.
       ctx.writeAndFlush(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Here are the questions:

1. Will creating a new Bootstrap client for each active channel reuse underlying connections?
2. Is there a risk that responses get tied to the wrong incoming request? (I think not due to http rules, but not 100% sure).
3. Is there an easier way to do it?
4. How should errors and timeouts be handled, particularly clean-up?
5. Is there an end-to-end example other that SocksProxy and HexDumpProxy?  This seems like an extremely common use case.

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.